# Magento override controller

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, cart

I would like to do the above.
Ive overridden many files in the past...block, model, helper....but this one eludes me.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here:
(ive edited this code...to include some of the recomendations now...)

Heres my folder structure (2 controller locations as a test):

```
/Idigital/Idgeneral/etc/config.xml
/Idigital/Idgeneral/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php
/Idigital/Idgeneral/controllers/CartController.php
```

Heres my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <idigital_idgeneral>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </idigital_idgeneral>
</modules>
<global>
<blocks>
        <idgeneral><class>Idigital_Idgeneral_Block</class></idgeneral>
    </blocks>
</global>   

<frontend>
    <routers>
                <checkout>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Idigital_Idgeneral before="Mage_Checkout">Idigital_Idgeneral_Checkout</Idigital_Idgeneral>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </checkout>
           </routers>
       <layout>   
        <updates>   
            <idgeneral>   
                <file>idigital.xml</file>   
            </idgeneral>   
        </updates>   
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Ihave placed my controller file in 2 locations to test.
And heres the top of my FIRST controller file:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Idigital_Idgeneral_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{


public function testAction()
{  
    var_dump('inside checkout/cart/test');exit; 
}

/**
 * Add product to shopping cart action
 */
public function addAction()
{
    blah...
}
```

Ans my second controller:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Idigital_Idgeneral_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{


public function testAction()
{  
    var_dump('inside cart/test');exit; 
}

/**
 * Add product to shopping cart action
 */
public function addAction()
{
    blah...
}
```

When i visit:  /checkout/cart/add
Im directed to the mage controller...not my local. (i have var_dump stmts in each..so i can see which is ran).

When i visit /checkout/cart/test    -  i get a 404
When i visit /cart/add  or cart/test   -  i get a 404 
when i visit idgeneral/cart/test   or   idgeneral/cart/add    -  i get a 404

Comment: I just tested your code of post revision#3 code against a naked CE 1.6.2.0. Requesting `checkout/cart/test` works for me and shows the expected result (`string(25) "inside checkout/cart/test"`). How does your module activation code (`app/etc/modules/whatever.xml`) look?

Answer (score 7):

1. Create your module folders and files

   ```
   app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/etc/config.xml
   app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php
   app/etc/modules/MyNameSpace_All.xml
   ```
2. Edit /etc/config.xml and Create app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/etc/config.xml with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
   <modules>
       <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
   </modules>
   <global>
       <!-- This rewrite rule could be added to the database instead -->
       <rewrite>
           <!-- This is an identifier for your rewrite that should be unique -->
           <!-- THIS IS THE CLASSNAME IN YOUR OWN CONTROLLER -->
           <mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart>
               <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
               <!--
                   - mymodule matches the router frontname below
                   - checkout_cart matches the path to your controller

                   Considering the router below, "/mymodule/checkout_cart/" will be
                   "translated" to "/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php" (?)
               -->
               <to>/mymodule/checkout_cart/</to>
           </mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart>
       </rewrite>
   </global>
   <!--
   If you want to overload an admin controller this tag should be <admin> instead,
   or <adminhtml> if youre overloading such stuff (?)
   -->
   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <mynamespace_mymodule>
               <!-- should be set to "admin" when overloading admin stuff (?) -->
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>MyNameSpace_MyModule</module>
                   <!-- This is used when "catching" the rewrite above -->
                   <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
               </args>
           </mynamespace_mymodule>
       </routers>
   </frontend>
   ```

   Note: The above didn’t work for me when I override catalog/product controller. I had to use:

   ```
               <from><![CDATA[#^catalog/product/#]]></from>
               <to>mymodule/mycontroller</to>
   ```

   (notice the missing leading slash)

   Since Magento 1.3 you can simply add your module to the frontend router. Rewrites are not neccessary any more:

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
   <modules>
       <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
   </modules>

   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <checkout>
               <args>
                   <modules>
                       <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNameSpace_MyModule</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
                   </modules>
               </args>
           </checkout>
       </routers>
   </frontend>
   ```

   Please note that `before=”Mage_Checkout”` will load your controller first if available and fall back to Magento’s if not.

   If the controller is in another folder, you’ll have to modify the code:
   `app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php.`

**Replace**

`<MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNameSpace_MyModule</MyNameSpace_MyModule>`

**with**

```
    <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNameSpace_MyModule_Checkout</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
```

1. Edit `'controllers/Checkout/CartController.php'`

   Create `app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php` with the following content: (the only change to indexAction() is adding an error_log() call):

   ```
       <?php
          # Controllers are not autoloaded so we will have to do it manually:
          require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
          class MyNameSpace_MyModule_Checkout_CartController extends
                          Mage_Checkout_CartController
       {
       # Overloaded indexAction
        public function indexAction() {
       # Just to make sure
       error_log('Yes, I did it!');
       parent::indexAction();
       }
        }
   ```

   1. Edit `'app/etc/modules/MyNameSpace_All.xml'`
      (This is to activate your module)

      true
              local
2. Edit `'app/design/frontend/[myinterface]/[mytheme]/layout/checkout.xml'` and add the following to use the same update handle as before:

   ```
    <mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart_index>
       <update handle="checkout_cart_index"/>
     </mynamespace_mymodule_checkout_cart_index>
   ```

   (Note that these tags seem to be case sensitive. Try using all lowercase if this isn’t working for you)

   [by Hendy: When I override catalog/product/view using the method described in this Wiki or here, I didn’t have to do the above. However, when using the 'cms way', I had to update the handle manually.]

   The above item did not work for me (2009-02-19 by Jonathan M Carvalho)

   I discovered that the file to change is app/design/frontend/[myinterface]/[mytheme]/layout/mymodule.xml

   Add the following lines:

   1. Point your browser to /checkout/cart/
      In your PHP error log, you should find ‘Yes, I did it!’.

   You need to be extra precise with the rewrite regular expression because errors are very hard to find.

Answer (score 6):

```
<Idigital_Idgeneral before="Mage_Checkout">Idgeneral_Checkout</Idigital_Idgeneral>
```

Should be

```
<Idigital_Idgeneral before="Mage_Checkout">Idigital_Idgeneral_Checkout</Idigital_Idgeneral>
```

or try moving your custom controller up to

```
../Idigital/Idgeneral/controllers/CartController.php
```

and use

```
<Idigital_Idgeneral before="Mage_Checkout">Idigital_Idgeneral</Idigital_Idgeneral>
```

There is also an error in your `<modules>` tag location. It should be:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <idigital_idgeneral>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </idigital_idgeneral>
    </modules>
    <global>
    ...
    </global>   

    <frontend>
        ....
    </frontend>
...
</config>
```

i.e `<modules>` shouldn't be inside `<global>`

Here's a good tutorial on how to dump the config tree that Magento sees as XML: http://alanstorm.com/magento_config

Comment: Hi. thx, i will try this.  I have already placed my controller up a level (so its now in 2 places, just so i can test) Why do you suggest using 'Idgeneral_Idgeneral'   if you mean:  'Idigital_Idgeneral'...then yes, i realised this. And tried it.
I will try out all your suggestions and get back to you. Controllers seem to be a pain. :(

Comment: My bad, you're right should be Idigital_Idgeneral.  If you do Idigital_Idgeneral combined with the controller up a level, should work.  You could try adding a custom action and hitting /checkout/cart/customaction to see if it lights up.

Comment: Hi, i tried all of these suggestions. Nothing works. Adding a test action also didnt work....and i tried this with all above suggestions...and clearing cache each time (which is also disabled).
What a pain!!
Given my test action didnt work, there must be an issue with the routing....any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your `<modules>` element is inside the `<global>` element in the config.xml.  It should be outside of the `<global>` element.  I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: EE wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: hi...didnt dspot that. Im adding TO this config...didnt build it  :(.

Answer (score 3):

I'm leaving this here for the next poor developer forced to work with this jalopy. Much of the instructions here are pasted from the [magento docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) which like its source, is a twisted labyrinth of misdirection. Okay enough complaints...

This worked for me in version 1.8

Create your namespace and module:
/app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule

Create your module config:
/app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNameSpace_MyModule_Checkout</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Create your controller:
/app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php';

class MyNameSpace_MyModule_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function indexAction() {
        // /var/log/debug.log should log the output
        Mage::log('cart index override', null, 'debug.log');

        // Call the parent class
        parent::indexAction();
    }
}
```

Enable your new module:
/app/etc/modules/MyNameSpace_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

That's all thats needed. Now go celebrate, you just polished a turd! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little notification on the include path of the controller.

This include path **can cause errors** if the **Magento Compiler mode** is turned on.

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
```

Instead of that it is **good to use**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php';
```

It will be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Well...it WONT override the checkout cart controller.

So i used the URL REWRITE in the PRODUCT VIEW...from this link...near the bottom of the article. They say its a proper method...

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax

```
if(!url){
      url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
}
url = url.replace("checkout/cart","idgeneral/cart");
```

That worked for me. Allows me to get cracking. Basically calls MY controller..instead of checkout controller.

Thanks for the help ROSCIUS...appreciated.

I also had to change my config....my routers section now looks like this:

```
<routers>
        <!-- THIS PART REGISTERS OUR CONTROLLERS FOLDER FOR USE -->
        <idgeneral>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Idigital_Idgeneral</module>
                <frontName>idgeneral</frontName>
            </args>
        </idgeneral>

        <!-- THIS PART WONT WORK TO OVERWRITE OUR MAGE CONTROLLER -->
        <checkout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Idigital_Idgeneral before="Mage_Checkout">Idigital_Idgeneral_Checkout</Idigital_Idgeneral>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
```