# Magento 1: app/code/local not overriding core file

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have copied the "`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`" to "`app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`" but it is not overriding the targeted file. what is getting wrong?

Comment: You can not override magento controller like this way.you have to create a module then override a the controller.

Comment: can you please explain how can I do it with minimum code?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12793093/1616003 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477461/1616003  Search Google for tutorials

Comment: Did you try solution provided by me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create following files:

1) app/etc/modules/Muk_Account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Muk_Account>
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Muk_Account>        
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) app\code\local\Muk\Account\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>   
        <Muk_Account>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Muk_Account>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Muk_Account before="Mage_Customer">Muk_Account_Customer</Muk_Account>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

3) app\code\local\Muk\Account\controllers\Customer\AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Muk_Account_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function createPostAction()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for help but dont know there is something getting wrong. are you sure there should be customer folder in controllers? I did as you said but sorry still no luck.

Comment: and there is no error showing but core file is executing still.

Comment: @Ren What do you want to override? You have to modify the code in the app\code\local\Muk\Account\controllers\Customer\AccountController.php file.Currently it is blank.

Comment: after changing the lines  <modules>
                        <Muk_Account before="Mage_Customer">Muk_Account_Customer</Muk_Account>
                    </modules> to  <modules>
                        <Muk_Account before="Mage_Customer">Muk_Account</Muk_Account>
                    </modules> and class name to Muk_Account_AccountController its working perfectly.